# Set the value of a column to its default value

Tags: postgresql, information-schema

I have few existing tables in which I have to modify various columns to have a default value.

How can I apply the default value to old records which are `NULL`, so that the old records will be consistent with the new ones

```
ALTER TABLE "mytable" ALTER COLUMN "my_column" SET DEFAULT NOW();
```

After modifying table looks something like this ...

```
    Table "public.mytable"
 Column      |            Type             |                        Modifiers
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                     | not null default nextval('mytable_id_seq'::regclass)
 ....

 my_column   | timestamp(0) with time zone | default now()

Indexes:
  "mytable_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Is there a simple to way to have all columns which are currently null and also which have a default value to be set to the default value ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Deriving from [`insert into`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/dml-insert.html):

> For clarity, you can also request default values explicitly, for individual columns or for the entire row:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO products (product_no, name, price) VALUES (1, 'Cheese', DEFAULT);
> INSERT INTO products DEFAULT VALUES;
> ```

I just tried this, and it is as simple as

```
update mytable
set my_column = default
where my_column is null
```

See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/db493/1)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**  [olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40056996/1900483) answer is easiest and correct way of doing this however the below also is viable solution for most cases.

For a each column it is easy to use the `information_schema` and get the default value of a column  and then use that in a `UPDATE` statement

```
UPDATE mytable set my_column = (
  SELECT column_default
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE (table_schema, table_name, column_name) = ('public', 'mytable','my_column')
)::timestamp
WHERE my_column IS NULL;
```

Note the sub-query must by typecast to the corresponding column data type .

Also this statement will not evaluate expressions as `column_default` will be of type character varying it will work for `NOW()` but not for expressions like say `(NOW()+ interval ' 7 days')`

It is better to get expression and validate it then apply it manually